# call block from controller via ajax

Tags: blocks, magento2.2.6, admin-controller

I call controller function from phtml via ajax, it calls controller function Now i am trying to call block function in controller it is not working

**Controller code**

```
 public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\LayoutFactory $resultLayoutFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->_registry = $registry;
        $this->_resultLayoutFactory = $resultLayoutFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        if($this->getRequest()->isAjax()){
            $start = $_POST['start'];
            $end = $_POST['end'];

            $enddate = date('Y-m-d 23:55:55', strtotime($end));
            $startdate = date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', strtotime($start));
            $resultLayout = $this->_resultLayoutFactory->create();
            $response = $resultLayout->getLayout()->getBlock('My\Module\Block\dashboard')->getprocesseddata();   
            return $response;         
        }

}
```

In block

```
 public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
        CardsManageFactory $cardsManageFactory,
        Data $helperData,
        array $data = [],        
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory,

        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Backend\Model\Session $session,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
    )
    {

        $this->_orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
        $this->_categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;

        parent::__construct($context, $data);

        $this->_cardsManageFactory = $cardsManageFactory;
        $this->_helperData         = $helperData;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig; // get api_key and secret_key
        $this->session = $session;
        $this->_registry = $registry;
    }

 public function getprocesseddata()
    {
      return 1;
}
```

while call controller execute from ajax . call is working. but from controller i cant call block

Answer (score 0):

Try below code in controller.

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultPageFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface $layout
) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    $this->_registry = $registry;
    $this->layout = $layout;
}

public function execute()
{
    if($this->getRequest()->isAjax()){
        $start = $_POST['start'];
        $end = $_POST['end'];

        $enddate = date('Y-m-d 23:55:55', strtotime($end));
        $startdate = date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', strtotime($start));
        $response = $this->layout->getBlock('My\Module\Block\dashboard')->getprocesseddata();   
        return $response;         
    }

}
```

I hope it'll help :)

Comment: Still i got the error @RamkishanSuthar

Comment: I got error the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error).

Comment: One more thing controller is the admin controller

Comment: In inspector preview didnt show anything

Comment: looks like you are on production mode. check logs

Comment: My system log file is empty.while check mode it returns mode is peoduction